# Move turtles around a patch

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to move turtle around patch 0 0 starting from random position in world. But circle keeps on growing. What am I doing wrong here?.

**Code:**

```
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 5
  ask turtles [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    ]
  ask patch 0 0 [ set pcolor green ]
  reset-ticks
end
to go 
  move-turtles
  tick
end
to move-turtles
  ask turtles
  [
    face patch 0 0
    right 90
    fd 0.01
    set pen-size 3
    pen-down
   ]
end
```

Secondly I want a turtle to move around any patch I define when it reaches with in a certain range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is to take a small step along a tangent to the circle you want, but this takes you a little bit outside the circle.  You do this repeatedly, so it accumulates over time.

For a better way, see the Turtles Circling example in the NetLogo Models Library.

Comment: In that example I don't understand where is it specifiying around which point it should mov? can you please help?

Comment: It goes around the point at distance `r` to its right.  You could modify the formula to move around an arbitrary circle.  Or you could circle around x, y like thils: `setxy x y fd r rt 90 move-around-circle r` (and then repeat that last command as much as wanted).